# How to migrate a web from Google cloud hosting to personnel domain?

Tags: web, migration, google-cloud-storage, cloud-hosting

**How to migrate a web from Google cloud hosting to personnel domain ??**

Answer (score 0):

As you use the "google-cloud-storage" tag, I am going to assume you are storing your website as static files in a GCS bucket and serving it from *bucket*.storage.googleapis.com or storage.googleapis.com/*bucket*.

The easiest options are:

1. Follow the [GCS Static Site](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) instructions to keep the content on GCS and serve it on your domain.
2. Download the files from https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser. Then upload the files to a shared hosting or VPS provider who will then serve the content on your domain.